# Friendstream App do not update Twitter,Facebook

Tags: htc-sense, htc-desire-hd, friendstream

I am unable to get Twitter, Facebook updates in FriendsStream App (HTC Sense) on my Desire HD.
anyone knows how to fix this?Right now only Flickr updates come and I used to get all the above before.

Answer (score 1):

Please, give more details. Have you saw twitter and facebook messages in the FriendStream before?

I have the same phone. Did you try to take a look at the "Menu->Settings->Show updates" in the FriendStream application? There are checkmarks for every stream-source.